# Replace first visit data with user selected data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a single page application that loads a string from a database into a partialview when a button is clicked, which is below and this works fine.

**View**

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button id="Button1" class="btn btn-warning btn-fill">Button1</button>
    <button id="Button2" class="btn btn-success btn-fill">Button2</button>
    <button id="Button3" class="btn btn-danger btn-fill">Button3</button>
</div>
<script>

    document.getElementById("Button1").onclick = function () { button1Function() };
    function button1Function() {

        $("#content").load('@Url.Action("Button1","Home")');

    }
    document.getElementById("Button2").onclick = function () { button2Function() };
    function button2Function() {

        $("#content").load('@Url.Action("Button2", "Home")');

    }
    document.getElementById("Button3").onclick = function () { button3Function() };
    function button3Function() {

        $("#content").load('@Url.Action("Button3", "Home")')

    }
</script>
```

But my problem is that when a user first visits the page they haven't yet pressed a button, and I want there to be a random string in it's place that disappears and/or is replaced by one of the button clicks.

I can't stop it from duplicating at the moment. How do I do this?

**Controller**

```
   public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            var activityid = db.Activities.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1);
            return View(activityid);
        }

        return View(db.Activities.Where(a => a.ActivityID == id));
    }

    public ActionResult Random()
    {
        return PartialView("_DisplayActivity", db.Activities.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1));
    }

    public ActionResult Button1()
    {
        var results1 = db.GetActivity(1);
        return PartialView("_DisplayActivity", results1);
    }

    public ActionResult Button2()
    {

        var results2 = db.GetActivity(2);
        return PartialView("_DisplayActivity", results2);
    }

    public ActionResult Button3()
    {
        var results3 = db.GetActivity(3);
        return PartialView("_DisplayActivity", results3 );
    }
```

**Example**

In example 1, this is how the page is displayed on first load. The second example is how it's rendered after one of the buttons have been pressed.

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

Comment: What's your mean of "from duplicating at the moment"?

Comment: I've added some pictures of what I mean.